# Blender Render Preview and saved Preview are completely different

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

[image]

Here is what my Render from Blender Eevee Should look like.  This is a rendered frame.  When I save this to my file folder, this is what I see:
[image]

Below are my render settings.  I've never had this problem before.  It renders at 50% and 100% correctly and when I render the image it's correct except when its saved it looks like an alpha channel. Im so confused.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkCBH.png)

[image]

Comment: Maybe some passes are disabled for the render, share the file so we can have a look at it

Comment: I might try saving the image directly from the render view image editor, rather than using the compositor to save it.

Comment: Hi :). This is a problem with the PNG format which doesn't support both transparent and emissive pixels. If you need it for compositing, use EXR. If you need a preview, render it on a black background :)